# How to load a hdfs parquet file to a HDFS table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to load a parquet file into a hdfs file table. Below is my sequence. First starting with creating my table.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    #from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
spark = (SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Test") \
        .getOrCreate())

spark.sql("create  external table if not exists table1 ( _c0 string, _c1 string, _c2 string, _c3 string, _c4 string, _c5 string, _c6 string) STORED AS parquet location 'hdfs://my_data/hive/db1/table1'") 

#table created successfully
```

Then I load my csv file and make sure the schema is the same at the table i created:

```
dp=spark.read.load("/user/path/test.parquet", format="parquet").printSchema()
```

[image]

Below is the parquet file content too:

[image]

[image]

And then I wrote it to the same path as the table i created above:

```
dp.write.save('hdfs://my_data/hive/db1/table1', format="parquet")
```

This runs successfully but when I select * from table1 no values show(see below):
[image]

DOes anyone know why no values are being inserted or it is showing nothing?Yes, there is data in the parquet file.

Comment: Whats the output of `spark.read.load("/user/path/test.parquet", format="parquet").count()` ?

Comment: I did the above statement and Output: 2

Comment: Do you think that may have something to do with the error?

Comment: delete printSchema() from dp and `dp.write.save` again.

Comment: I did already. I just showed printSchema() to show the schema.

Comment: Try: `dp.write.option("path", hdfs://my_data/hive/db1").saveAsTable("table1")`

If nothing appears try to run  `INVALIDATE METADATA;` before the select command

Comment: what should be in between the "path"